# Can I open Multiple App within 1 app using Xcode Workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace

I have build simple five iOS App.I want to open all five app using 1 master App.I have seen people are talking about XcodeWorkspace can do the same.Is it possible with XcodeWorkspace? or is there any way to achieve this task?

Comment: Have you tried to use Xcode Workspaces for this?

Comment: I can add multiple project in workspace and run separate Targets by changing scheme but how to make it programmatically run separate target.

Comment: on Tapping on Button.